# Cardinality of two power sets Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Problem 5 (2 pts)
Given two finite sets A and B with the cardinalities  A= n and B = m.
(a) What is the cardinality of the powerset P(A x B)?
(b) How many functions is there from A to B?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

(a) In general, if $A$ is a set containing the $n$ elements $a_1,a_2\ldots,a_n$, then the power set of $A$ will contain $2^n$ elements.

Indeed, a subset of $A$ is completely determined by its elements. So, there are as many subsets of $A$ as there are ways to choose elements in $A$. Now,
$$
\text{Either you choose }a_1\text{ or you don't choose }a_1\text{: that's $2$ choices}\\
\text{Either you choose }a_2\text{ or you don't choose }a_2\text{: that's $2$ choices}\\
\vdots\\
\text{Either you choose }a_n\text{ or you don't choose }a_n\text{: that's $2$ choices}
$$
By the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) in combinatorics, you have
$$
\underbrace{2\times2\times\cdot\times2}_{n\text{ times}}=2^n
$$
ways to choose elements in $A$, that is, there are $2^n$ subsets of $A$.

So all you have to do is find the number of elements in $A\times B$, which you can do via the same rule of product. Elements of $A\times B$ are of the form $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. How many of these couples exist?
$$
\text{As a first choice, select $a\in A$: this can be done in $n$ ways}\\
\text{As a second choice, select $b\in B$: this can be done in $m$ ways}
$$
By the rule of product, there are $n\times m$ such couples, that is, $|A\times B|=nm$.

Hence the cardinality of the powerset of $A\times B$ is $2^{nm}$.

(b) What choices are you to make in order to completely specify a function from $A$ to $B$? You have $n$ actions to do: for each element of $A$, you have to assign a unique element of $B$.
$$
\text{For $a_1$, select a $b\in B$: this can be done in $m$ ways}\\
\text{For $a_2$, select a $b\in B$: this can be done in $m$ ways}\\
\vdots\\
\text{For $a_n$, select a $b\in B$: this can be done in $m$ ways}\\
$$
By the rule of product, there are thus
$$
\underbrace{m\times m\times\cdots\times m}_{n\text{ times}}=m^n
$$
functions from $A$ to $B$.